# How to show a form under a div depending on button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to display a form under a div using JavaScript depending on an external id which I pass to the function creating the form.

```
function reply(reply){
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    var textfield = document.createElement('textfield')
    var submit = document.createElement('input')
    form.setAttribute('action',"\"sendcomment("+ array[i].pk +")\"" )
    textfield.className = "commenttextfield"
    textfield.setAttribute('placeholder',"reply..." )
    submit.setAttribute('type',"submit" )
    submit.className="commentformsubmit"
    form.appendChild(textfield);
    form.appendChild(submit);
}
```

I have a lot of div's with id's like `comment-id-X` where `X` is a unique number.the value of X is passed to the function above as reply. So I need to do something like `form.placeunder("comment-box-"+ reply)`. I tried to do:

```
document.getElementById('comment-id-'+ reply).appendChild(form);
```

which causes an error saying:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null.
```

what causes this?

Also the div's have a variable left-margin style attribute which I would like that the form also would have. Is that possible?

the divs I need to append to are generated by javascript also like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    //setup list item
    var item = document.createElement('li');
    item.clasName = "commentlistelement"
    //setup parent div
    var maindiv = document.createElement('div')
    maindiv.setAttribute('id',"comment-id-" + array[i].pk);
    maindiv.className = "row comment";
    maindiv.setAttribute("style","padding-left: "+3*array[i].fields.indent+"vw;");
    //fill parent div (the reply button triggers the function above)
    maindiv.innerHTML = "<div class=\"col-md-1\">profile<br>pic</div><div class=\"col-md-9\"><small>username  </small><small><button class=\"buttonlink\" onclick=\"reply("+ array[i].pk +")\">reply</button></small><br><p>" + array[i].fields.description + "</p></div>"
    //append div to list item and list item to list
    item.appendChild(maindiv);
    list.appendChild(item);
}
```

Comment: `I have a lot of div's with id's like comment-box-X` . `document.getElementById('comment-id-'+ reply` ...spot the difference. box != id

Comment: if you have a lot of `comment-box-X` why are you trying to reference them using `'comment-id-X'`..... don't you notice that box and id are two different things?

Comment: You should not use textfield but textarea.

Comment: typo sorry.....

Comment: And yes of course you can add the same margin value to the form, either add the same class (if the rule is derived from a class) or set the style attribute of the form appropriately. Of course if you're appending the form as a child of the div, then it'll be within that div anyway and so it will be within the div's left margin already

Comment: Sybaris is right, textfield is not a valid kind of HTML element. Use a textarea (big box), or an input field with text type (regular one-line textbox).

Comment: But yeah if that comment-box thing was a typo then you need to show us the related HTML you're working with.

Comment: Run your script and make sure that `document.getElementById('comment-id-'+ reply)` is actually returning a valid object. if it isnt log `reply` and see what does it contains

Comment: The related HTML is also generated by javasctipt... still I can add it if you want EDIT: I did

Comment: `pk` is an attribute of an array I get from parsing a Json response

Comment: using inspect element in firefox I checked and it actually places the right number there (it corisponse with it's `pk` in the database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution for your problem but before i want to mention some things
1-there's no textfield element in html (maybe you are mistaken this for textarea)
2-you have to rename you variable reply the function reply so that your code will bot confuse them

```js
function replyFn() {
  var form = document.createElement('form');
  form.className = 'formcomment'
  var textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
  var submit = document.createElement('input')
  //form.setAttribute('action', "\"sendcomment(" + array[i].pk + ")\"")
  textarea.className = "commenttextfield"
  textarea.innerText = "reply..."
  submit.setAttribute('type', "submit")
  submit.className = "commentformsubmit"
  form.appendChild(textarea);
  form.appendChild(submit);
  return form;
}

function showForm(reply) {

  var form = replyFn();
  document.getElementById('comment-id-' + reply).appendChild(replyFn());
  alert(document.getElementsByClassName('formcomment').length)

}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="reply" onclick="showForm(1)">
<div id="comment-id-1" class="comment-id-1"></div>
```

Comment: That seems to work. however now I can click it and every time it creates a new one. So I tried testing if it allready is there like this: `if($("#comment-id-"+ id).length == 2){` I do  `length == 2` because there is allready another 2 divs inside before adding the form but this does not work. printing `$("#comment-id-"+ id).length` returns 1 but it does not increase for every form I put under it. Do you know whats up with that?

Comment: This might work if it's empty but there are 2 divs (of which the content is variable) inside it all ready as I add the form so I can't test if it's empty. Thats why i tried the thing with the length

Comment: do you mean that when i click reply button it shows two forms ?

Comment: no the div when you test this: `if (document.getElementById('comment-id-' + reply).innerHTML == "")` is not empty as there are allready 2 divs there when I create the form (which are there on purpose and actually have to be there)

Comment: so I can't test if they are empty

Comment: you cant use it with the length because the id is unique and getElementById will return 1 always

Comment: so then how can i check how many divs are in the `document.getElementById('comment-id-' + reply)` div?

Comment: you should use the class insead of using the id check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp)

Comment: how do you mean that?